# Drawing polygon and summarizing values in map on Portal for ArcGIS?

Tags: polygon, arcgis-portal, summarizing

I have a map application created in Portal for ArcGIS. I have a points layer in the map. Each point has a numeric value. I want to be able to draw a polygon on the map, containing some of the points. It is fine if it is just a markup. I want to sum the numeric values from the points in the polygon and show the result in the app.

Are there any widgets or other ready made functionality I can make use of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved using the Situation Awareness widget.

The way I solved it was just to add the Situation Awareness widget to the ArcGIS Portal web app and link up the layers, and fields. So useful summaries were returned inside the area of interest drawn.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/169109)

Comment: I answered my own question. The way I solved it was just to add the Situation Awareness widget to the ArcGIS Portal web app and link up the layers, and fields, so useful summaries were returned inside the area of interest drawn.